# Show total calculated records of first page on top of next page in crystal reports using c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have calculated customers records on first page in crystal reports which i am getting from database and now i want to show these calculated records on top of next page of crystal reports using c#.

Comment: You need to give us a little more than that. How is the report structured? Do you have groups? In what section of the report are these calculated records?